# JQuery/Javascript Fade In On Scroll Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on some content that requires an image to fade in at the bottom of the scroll. I have attached my JSFiddle to this in hopes of getting some help. It seems that when I remove the class, the image appears just fine. Not sure what to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/1ak7q0kg/3/

HTML

```
<div id="slide1">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>This is a title</h2>
                   <div class="quotes_container">
                   <h3 class="quotes">“Below this content, an image is supposed to fade in.”  </h3>
                       <div class="fadeInBlock"><img src="http://www.strangetravel.com/images/content/120195.jpg"></div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){


        $('.fadeInBlock').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or that the content starts fading a bit before you reach it  */
            bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 200;  

            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);

            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

CSS

```
.fadeInBlock {opacity:0;}
```

Comment: You didn't add jquery. Is this how it should work? https://jsfiddle.net/1ak7q0kg/4/

Comment: @Petey Pretty sure you are mixing up opacity of 100% (1) and opacity of 0 (0%). To fade something in you would want an opacity of 1 not 0. If something is 100% opaque you cannot see through it at all, it is a solid wall. If something is 0% opaque it is completely transparent, completely see through.

Comment: @MichaelCoker That's how it should look. I have JQuery called in my document but still not getting the result you have.

Comment: @Petey you need to give us a [mcve] that illustrates the problem, otherwise we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
  $(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){


        $('.fadeInBlock').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or that the content starts fading a bit before you reach it  */
            bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 200;  

            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);

            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

**YOU DID NOT INCLUDE JQUERY SO USE**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And finally uour HTML:
I included an image from an https source as it was throwing an insecure origin error in jsfiddle.

```
<div id="slide1">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>This is a title</h2>
               <div class="quotes_container">
               <h3 class="quotes">“Below this content, an image is supposed to fade in.”  </h3>
                   <div class="fadeInBlock"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"></div>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

This works . Tested it on JS Fiddle.